# interface implementation with additional default arguments?

Tags: c++, oop

I have a question about implementing interface in C++:

Suppose there is an interface:

```
class A
{
 virtual void f() = 0;
};
```

When implementing this, I wonder if there's a way to do something like:

```
class B : public A {     
  void f(int arg=0) {....} // unfortunately it does not implement f() this way
};
```

I want to keep the iterface clean. When client code calls through public interface A, arg is always set to 0 automatically. However when I call it through B, I have the flexibility to call it with arg set to some different value. Is it achievable?

EDIT: Since I control the interface and implementation, I am open to any suggestions, Macros, templates, functors, or anything else that makes sense. I just want to have a minimal and clean code base. The class is big, and I don't want to write any code that not absolutely necessary - e.g. another function that simply forwards to the actual implementation.

EDIT2: Just want to clarify a bit: The public interface is provided to client. It is more restrictive than Class B interface, which is only used internally. However the function f() is essentially doing the same thing, other than minor different treatment based on input arg. The real class has quite some interface functions, and the signature is complex. Doing function forwarding quickly results in tedious code repetition, and it pollutes the internal interface for B. I wonder what is the best way to deal with this in C++.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, just make two separate functions:

```
class B : public A {     
    void f() { return f(0); }
    void f(int arg) { .... }
};
```

Comment: Yes, that will work. However it's a big class, and effectively I have to add a lot of forwarding members in B, which makes it very cluttered.. I am trying to avoid that.

Comment: @ttrrxx: you can't override a function with a function that takes different arguments, unfortunately. This happens to include default-argument functions.

If it concerns you, you might be able to write a macro to write the forwarding members for you.

Comment: thanks.. Since I control the interface and implementation, I am open to any suggestions, Macros, templates, functors, or anything else that makes sense. I just want to have a minimal and clean code base. Hopefully there's some creative way of doing this.

Comment: No it won't work in that way. `void f()` and `void f(arg)` are 2 different function signature even you have a default argument value.

Comment: @ttrrxx this is the proper solution to the problem that you posted. However, you seem to have another problem: the big class B whose interface functions don't seem to quite fit A's virtual interface. This could be an issue with A's virtual interface being too restricted or with B having too big an interface, i.e. maybe violationg the SRP. Or maybe you should flesh out an implementation class that has `f(int)`, and `B` is just a adaptor that holds such an impl and forwards `f()` to `impl::f(0)`

Comment: Interface A is intentionally more restrictive.. I added some more clarification to the original question. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

When you have an interface, the basic principle should be that a function ALWAYS takes the same arguments and ALWAYS operates in the same way, no matter what the derived class is doing. Adding extra arguments is not allowed, because that presumes that the "thing" that operates on the object "knows" what the argument is/does.

There are several ways around this problem - thre that spring to mind immediately are:

1. Add the argument to the interface/baseclass.
2. Don't use an argument, but some extra function that [when the derived object is created or some other place that "knows the difference"] stores the extra information inside the object that needs it.
3. Add another class that "knows" what the argument is inside the class.

An example of the second one would be:

```
class B: public A
{  
   private:
     int x; 
   public:
     B() x(0) { ... }   // default is 0. 
     void f() { ... uses x ... }
     void setX(int newX) { x = newX; };
     int getX() { return x; }
};
```

So, when you want to use `x` with another value than zero, you call `bobject->setX(42);` or something like that.

Comment: Problem is that I need to enforce client calls from interface A always have arg set to 0. If x is set to 1 through the internal interface B accidentally, then client access to f() will have arg set to 1, which will be bad.

Answer (score 0):

From your descriptions I'd say you should provide two classes, both with a specific responsibility: One to implement the desired functionality, the other to provide the needed interface to the client. That way you separate concerns and dont violate the SRP:

```
class BImpl {
public:
  doF(int arg);  
};

class B : public A {
  BImpl impl;
public:
  virtual void f() override {
    impl.doF(0);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

> Doing function forwarding quickly results in tedious code repetition, and it pollutes the internal interface for B. I wonder what is the best way to deal with this in C++.

It sounds like you need to write a script to automate part of the process.